# ReferenceError in Dart: function is not defined when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html, dart

I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first real project. I'm making a small game in Dart from one in JS.

I have the following lines of codes in my `head` section of my HTML document:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
<script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

And this `td` under a `tr` in a `table` in the `body`:

```
 <td style="width:300px"><button type="button" name="playstop" onclick="play()"> Play Stop </button></td>
```

The function it refers to is in my `main.dart`:

```
play() {
    if (playing=true) {
        stop();
        return;
    }
    playing=true;
    clear();
    totalhits=0;
    state.querySelectorAll('[value="Playing"]');
    start();
    showtime(gamelength);
}
```

Now everytime I run the build from my editor it works fine, everything is where it's supposed to be. Once I click the startstop button, however, it gives me a `referenceError` and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Rich: Replace `if (playing=true) {` with `if (playing==true) {`. It will not help, but it is a bug in your code.

Comment: Try to move your `script` elements from `head` to the end of `body`. Does this help? It’s shown in the [official tutorial to linking Dart to HTML](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/connect-dart-html/#create-html).

Comment: You're right on the ==true, thank you for spotting that.

I've tried moving it around, beginning of head, end of head, beginning of body, end of body, still the same error :(

Comment: It makes no sense checking `== true` inside a boolean expression though, `if(playing)` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's disallowed using `onclick` in html https://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/

I suggest you to use

```
  var elem = querySelectorAll('[name="startstop"]');

  elem.onClick.listen(
      (event) => play);
```

in your main().